# How to initialize a mutable char array that consists of multiple variables

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char, esp32

So I have this small code I'm running on an ESP32-S2. I also use Platform IO and Arduino Code Base.
There is a lib with a header file and cpp file.
So I would like to create a char array that is build up from multiple variables and maybe some fixed text.
As an example:

Header file:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private:
        const char* _someConstCharArray;
        char _someCharArray[100];
    public:
        SomeClass();
}
```

Cpp file:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass() : _someConstCharArray("test")
{
    sprintf(_someCharArray,"thisisaurl/%s/set",_someConstCharArray);
}
```

This works reasonably, however the _someCharArray has a fixed size while I only know the size in the constructor. I'm happy to allocate the size there if that is possible.
I also tried a bunch of other stuff that did compile but failed on the board.
I've read that I should avoid strings due to memory fragmentation and what not, but I'm happy to use them if someone can convince me it is the best solution.
Could you help me in obtaining a nice and proper way to create a char array, or string for that matter, that is build from multiple other variables and/or static text inside the constructor without having to write a dozen strcpy/strcat statements?

Comment: _"that is build from multiple other variables and/or static text inside the constructor"_: please clarify and possibly add an example of how you would use the class.

Comment: If you are going to allocate the memory needed for the string then you are potentially going to get fragmentation. So in that case you might as well use `std::string`. That's really the choice here, fixed size buffers, or dynamic allocation using `std::string`. Also `std::string` has a `reserve` method that will, as far as possible, avoid memory fragmentation.

Comment: If you're programming with the Arduino standard classes, then you should have a [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class which is dynamic. But note that there are downsides to this, especially on small embedded systems like an Arduino.

Comment: If you are dynamically allocating memory in any way, then you are building a design that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

My doubts about strings are caused by mixed posts about it. Reading the answers didn't take away my doubts. I decided to go with this.

Header file:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private:
        const char* _someConstCharArray;
        char *_someCharArray;
    public:
        SomeClass();
}
```

Cpp file:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass() : _someConstCharArray("test")
{
    _someCharArray = new char[strlen("thisisaurl/") + strlen(_someConstCharArray) + strlen("/set") + 1];
    sprintf(_someCharArray,"thisisaurl/%s/set",_someConstCharArray);
}
```

If you see any issues with this let me know. Not the most elegant construction, but it appears to work quite well for now.